# When we are walking or running, which friction is exerted on our feet? Kinetic or static?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

As already mentioned in the title, when we are walking or running on the floor, which friction is exerted on our feet? Kinetic friction or static friction?

In my understanding, the answer is static friction because our feet do not slide on the floor. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Kinetic friction acts when sliding only. Of course there is an instant of time where your feet slide. But you can despise that...

Comment: Sorry, do you know the source of your theory? :-)

Comment: You can read it [here](http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/ns540_fall10_notes06/NS540_online3.pdf)